# Как сделать overflow: hidden только для определенной стороны объекта?

Tags: css, hidden

Добрый день уважаемые. Такой вопрос как сделать скрытие элемента только с определенных сторон? 
При overflow: hidden Отображается только область внутри элемента, остальное будет скрыто.
Представим себе простую задачу, есть два div-а, один находиться в другом.
преобразуем вложенный див в круг, и сделаем ему размеры больше наружного. Если наружному задать overflow: hidden он обрежет со всех сторон наш круг. Как сделать так что б, допустим сверху наш вложенный див не обрезался ?

Comment: какая картинка в итоге должна получиться?

Comment: На выходе должно получится два дива, один из которых частично перекрывает второй. Как-то так. Я надеюсь вы понимаете, о чём я [otvet.png](https://postimg.org/image/4030c3dub/)